# What is balanceRecived in solidity? what it will be strore?

Tags: methods, blockchain, ethereum, solidity

i am begginer can any one explain me what is balanceRecived in solidity? what it will be strore?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity ^0.8.1;

contract SendMoneyExample {

    uint public balanceReceived;

    function receiveMoney() public payable {
        balanceReceived += msg.value;
    }

    function getBalance() public view returns(uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }

    function withdrawMoney() public {
        address payable to = payable(msg.sender);
        to.transfer(getBalance());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time when someone executes the `receiveMoney()` function, it happens as a result of a transaction.

A transaction can hold `value` in the form of the network native currency. Your question is tagged `Ethereum`, and the native currency for the Ethereum network is `ETH`. *(If the contract was on the Binance Smart Chain network, the native currency would be `BNB`, the Tron network has `TRX`, and so on...)*

So each time the `receiveMoney()` function is executed, in adds the current transaction value to the total number hold in `balanceReceived`.

---

Example:

1. First transaction executing `receiveMoney()`, sending along 1 wei (the smallest unit of ETH). The value of `balanceReceived` becomes 1.
2. Second transaction executing `receiveMoney()`, sending along 5 wei. The value of `balanceReceived` becomes 6.